# zoom out Grantt chart SharePoint 2013 through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to zoom out SharePoint 2013 Grantt Chart so that it only shows month in scale.

I have seen few examples which shows the same thing but none of them is working for me.

http://sharepoint.aspcode.net/view/63539928672422258262664/can-the-zoomscale-on-js-grid-conrol-in-gantt-mode-be-changed

http://sharepoint.aspcode.net/view/635399286724222582149020/gantt-chart-scale